# How to use Bindings.when to bind button disableProperty with a TableView Selecteditem property

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView that holds a Model class, which has a BooleanProperty as follow

```
@FXML
TableView<Model> tableView;
```

***Model Class :***

```
class Model{

BooleanProperty valid;

public Model()
{
valid = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
}
... getters and setters
}
```

What i want to acheive is to bind a button disable property with selected item valid Property in the Model class fom the tableView, i know that i can acheive that with listeners, but using a listener needs to set first the initial value properly, since they are not getting fired until there is some change, as an exemple in this case, if there is no selected item from the table and the button is set to be not disable from the start, it will still be like that, until the listener fired, this is why i prefer to use Bindings, since it doesn't care about the initial value. is there any way to do so with Bindings also ?

***what i tried :***

i tried this :

```
transferButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.when(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNotNull()).then(
               tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().valideProperty()
        ).otherwise(false));
```

but the problem is that i'm getting the following error :

```
return value of "javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem()" is null
```

Even tho i put a condition to the binding : `Bindings.when(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNotNull()`

Comment: I removed the tags for javafx 2, 8, and 11 because you are probably not using any of those versions and definitely not all of those versions at the same time.  Just the javafx tag is enough I think.  If you want to state the specific version of JavaFX you are using, you can just write it in the question, preferably the full version info, e.g. 17.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach of a custom select binding which uses functions to provide nested properties (similar to core SelectBinding, just replacing the reflective access to the nested properties by functions providing them)

The basic idea

- start with binding to the root
- keep the binding chain in the dependencies
- update the binding chain on validating (no need to do anything as long as the binding is not valid)
- implement state cleanup

Code example (here with a single function only, can be extended for a longer chain, though, by adding more functions and walk the providers)

```
/**
 * Custom binding to a nested property using a Function to provide the nested. 
 */
public class XSelectBinding<R, T> extends ObjectBinding<T> {

    private ObservableList<ObservableValue<?>> dependencies;
    private Function<R, ObservableValue<T>> provider;

    public XSelectBinding(ObservableValue<R> root, Function<R, ObservableValue<T>> provider) {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("root must not be null");
        }
        if (provider == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("provider must not be null");
        }
        dependencies = FXCollections.observableArrayList(root);
        this.provider = provider;
        bind(root);
    }

    /**
     * Implemented to update dependencies and return the value of the nested property if
     * available
     */
    @Override
    protected T computeValue() {
        onValidating();
        ObservableValue<?> child = dependencies.size() > 1 ? dependencies.get(1) : null;
        return child != null ? (T) child.getValue() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Updates dependencies and bindings on validating.
     */
    protected void onValidating() {
        // grab the root
        ObservableValue<R> root = (ObservableValue<R>) dependencies.get(0);
        // cleanup bindings and dependencies
        unbindAll();

        // rebind starting from root
        dependencies.add(root);
        ObservableValue<T> nestedProperty = root.getValue() != null ?
                provider.apply(root.getValue()) : null;
        if (nestedProperty != null) {
            dependencies.add(nestedProperty);
        }
        bind(dependencies.toArray(new ObservableValue<?>[dependencies.size()]));
    }

    /**
     * Unbinds and clears dependencies.
     */
    private void unbindAll() {
        unbind(dependencies.toArray(new ObservableValue<?>[dependencies.size()]));
        dependencies.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<?> getDependencies() {
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(dependencies);
    }

    /**
     * Implemented to unbind all dependencies and clear references to path providers.
     */
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        unbindAll();
        provider = null;
    }

}
```

To use in the OP's context:

```
// XSelectBinding
ObjectBinding<Boolean> xSelectBinding = new XSelectBinding<Model, Boolean>(
            table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(),
            item -> item.validProperty());
transferButton.disableProperty().bind(BooleanExpression.booleanExpression(xSelectBinding).not());
```

Comment: thank you, its working amazingly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom binding which implements a listener: for example:

```
transferButton.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {
    {
        tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (oldSelection != null) unbind(oldSelection.validProperty());
            if (newSelection != null) bind(newSelection.validProperty());
            invalidate();
        });
        bind(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        Model selection = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selection == null) return true ;
        return ! selection.isValid();
    }
});
```

There is also a [`selection`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#select(javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue,java.lang.String...)) API in the `Bindings` API which will work, though it is not robust and will generate spurious warnings when the selection is null:

```
transferButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.selectBoolean(
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(),
    "valid"
)).not());
```

Comment: it's a bit cheating (because at the bottom you have a listener :) The basic issue is that path properties are not supported (neither in bindings nor in listening). But then, I rarely understand questions like these ("I know how to use it with a listener but want to do it in a different manner").

Comment: @kleopatra Fair comment; though I'm implementing a custom binding, and ultimately all binding implementations use listeners *somewhere*.

Comment: @kleopatra The issue with listeners is that there must be a change from the initial value to be fired, not like Bindings, thats why i didn't want to use listeners and was searching for a way using "Bindings" instead

Comment: @James_D thank you, may i ask if if you have any idea why Bindings condition is not working ? even tho i put the condition "Bindings.when(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNotNull()"

Comment: @YoussefIdraiss The `then` clause is evaluated no matter the value of the `when` condition. If you actually think about implementing this with the method signature that's given (i.e. `then(Observable)`) it *has* to be done that way. Arguably it would have been better to have something like `then(Supplier<Observable>)`, in which case evaluation could be deferred and then could be only performed if the boolean value in `when` were true; but these were all written pre-Java 8, so using an API like that would have been very cumbersome.

Comment: @YoussefIdraiss The `select` API was an attempt to do something like that, but due to constraints of not having lambdas and type inference, etc. (i.e. pre Java 8) the only reasonable way to do it was with reflection and naming properties as strings, which is highly non-robust. (On top of that the API designers don't seem to have been able to agree among themselves if having a `null` in the "chain" was supported or not.) There's a discussion [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091544)

Comment: _The issue with listeners is that there must be a change from the initial value to be fired, not like Bindings_ hmm ... don't know what you mean. Care to elaborate (in the question, not in a comment :)? Sounds like a not yet mentioned constraint plus relying on potentially unspecified behavior (of bindings)

Comment: sure .. was just a bit of nit-picking :) Plus: your custom binding implementation deviates from core bindings in not listening weakly (which may or not be a problem)

Comment: @kleopatra *"The issue with listeners is that there must be a change from the initial value to be fired, not like Bindings"* I think what is meant here is that `a.bind(b)` will immediately update `a`, but to do the same with listeners requires the somewhat unwieldy `b.addListener((o,t1,t2) -> a.set(t1)); a.set(b.get());`.

Comment: @kleopatra i updated my question to make it more clear "using a listener needs to set first the initial value properly, since they are not getting fired until there is some change, as an exemple in this case, if there is no selected item from the table and the button is set to be not disable from the start, it will still be like that, until the listener fired, this is why i prefer to use Bindings", i also prefere Bindings since they are more readable and they make the code cleaner, but it looks there is no way to do so directly.

Comment: thanks for the clarification :)